# How big is PATA throughput on original Macbook Air (Rev A)?

Tags: mac, memory, ssd, pata, paging

I still have one of the original Macbook Air's that I use sometimes. It's got 2Gb of RAM and whenever it's filling up and starts paging, the whole things becomes barely responsive.

I've heard SSD's make paging much faster and I'd like to try putting one in. I don't want to spend much as this laptop doesn't get used much.

For little above $100 I can get a 64Gb SSD with 80/40Mb read/write speeds, or I can get much faster drive for 50-70% more. The question is how much fast do I want it, it's PATA and it might have a very limited throughput. Does anyone have exact numbers?

Thanks!